# What is the operator precedence for quantifiers?

Tags: first-order-logic

Is the term
$$\forall x p(x) \rightarrow \forall x q(x)$$
equal to
$$\forall x (p(x) \rightarrow \forall x q(x))$$
or
$$(\forall x p(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x q(x))$$

In other words: What is the operator precedence of $\forall$ and $\exists$?
Does it make a difference?

Comment: You have to use parentheses; $∀x(p(x) \to ∀xq(x))$ is equivalent to : $∃xp(x) \to  ∀xq(x)$. Thus, in $∀xp(x) \to ∀xq(x)$ we assume that the *scope* of the leftmost quantifiers is only $p(x)$. In other words, the quantifiers has the same priority that $\lnot$, i.e. higher than the binary *connectives*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you want to say that $\forall x p(x) \rightarrow \forall x q(x)$ is not a valid formula?

Comment: It is, Moose. The second choice is equivalent to your posted statement, but not the first choice you give.$$\forall x p(x) \rightarrow \forall x q(x) \equiv (\forall x p(x)) \rightarrow (\forall x q(x))$$

Comment: Of course it is admissible; but if you ask if it is "well-formed" you have to check with your specifications. If you ask if is a "correct" abbreviation, my answer is : **YES**, but I read it as : $((∀xp(x)) → (∀xq(x)))$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no "precedence" between quantifiers: in a formula like $\forall x \ \exists y \ \varphi$, the "inner" $\exists$ is in the *scope* of the "outer" $\forall$.

The *recursive* definition of *formula* for FOL is (having defined *term*) more or less this :

> *(i)* $t_1=t_2$ and $P^n(t_1,\ldots,t_n)$ are *atomic* formulas, where $t_1,\ldots,t_n$ are *terms* and $P^n$ is a $n$-ary *predicate* symbol;
>
> *(ii)* if $\varphi, \psi$ are formulas, then $\lnot \varphi, \varphi \land \psi, \varphi \lor \psi, \varphi \to \psi$ are *formulas*;
>
> *(iv)* if $\varphi$ is a formula, then $((∀x)\varphi), ((∃x)\varphi)$ are formulas.

Then we **can** introduce abbreviations for readibility; see :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA78), page 78 :

> For parentheses we will omit mention of just as many as we possibly can. Toward that end we adopt the following conventions:
>
> 1. Outermost parentheses may be dropped. For example, $∀x α → β$ is $(∀x α → β)$.
> 2. $\lnot, ∀$, and $∃$ apply to as little as possible. For example,
>
> > $¬α ∧ β$ is $((¬α) ∧ β)$, and not $¬(α ∧ β)$;
> >
> > $∀x α → β$ is $(∀x α → β)$, and not $∀x(α → β)$;
> >
> > $∃x α ∧ β$ is $(∃x α ∧ β)$, and not $∃x(α ∧ β)$.
>
> In such cases we might even add gratuitous parentheses, as in $(∃x α)∧β$.
>
> 3. ∧ and ∨ apply to as little as possible, subject to item 2. For example, $¬α ∧ β → γ$ is $((¬α) ∧ β) → γ$.
> 4. When one connective is used repeatedly, the expression is grouped to the right. For example, $α → β → γ$ is $α → (β → γ)$.

Thus, we have a "formal" *specification* for the syntax: it must be unambiguous, i.e. "processable" by a machine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. ((2) was what I needed to know)